# How do I use natbib and agsm

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I am trying to use `natbib` and `agsm` for harvard style in my work but without success. Given the code below I get output: ...(?) in the pdf and a warning in the console:

```
pdflatex> Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.
```

If I change the bibstyle to `plainnat` it works.

Whats wrong in this example? how can I make `agsm` work as bibstyle?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{goossens93,
        author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach and Alexander Samarin",
        title = "The Latex Companion",
        year = "1993",
        publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
        address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
} 
\end{filecontents}

...test\citep{goossens93}

\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is working fine for me. Can you make sure that `agsm.bst` is available in `texmf` path? You can check it by `kpsewhich agsm.bst` in command-line. If the package lists, then can you please post the  log file of `bibtex`.

Comment: kpsewhich agsm.bst gives no output when used in the command line.

Comment: Then, it seems that agsm.bst is missing. Can you please download it from [ctan](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/agsm.bst) and copy to your working directory and try `pdflatex bibtex pdflatex pdflatex` on file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Followed your advice and it works now! Thx

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a missing .bst file